# How to merge multiple arrays into an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

This is my current `output`, consisting of multiple `arrays`:

```
["{"486|575":2,"484|568":4}", "{"486|575":2,"484|568":4}", "{"481|570":1,"482|564":1}"]
```

And i'm looking for a way to combine these multiple arrays into an `object` with the following `output` using js/jquery:

```
{486|575: 4, 484|568: 8, 481|570: 1, 482|564: 1}
```

See how the key values of the duplicates sums up into the object?

How do i solve this? i'm relatively new to js/jquery!

Comment: I see you have only one array, Can you elaborate the question more.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use `reduce` function of `JavaScript`. Here is how you can do this:

```js
var data =[{"486|575":2,"484|568":4}, {"486|575":2,"484|568":4}, {"481|570":1,"482|564":1}];

var result= data.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(elem)){
      acc[key] = acc[key] || 0;
      acc[key] += value;
   }
   return acc;
},{})

console.log(result)
```